# CvQueryHistValue_1D on iOS?

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm currently developing an iOS App with OpenCV framework, everything's OK until I've tried to include this line of code

```
value=cvQueryHistValue_1D(hist,i);
```

That's when XCode tells me "Use of undeclared identifier cvQueryHistValue_1D". I can't find any information about this, as many tutorials use that call and is supposed to work fine. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include compat.hpp

```
#include <opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp>
```